# Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: centos, networking, opensuse

To set IP address on CentOS 7, I study [this page](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setting-rhel7-centos-7-static-ip-configuration/) in which a `ifcfg-eth0` file is created and then this command is run:

```
systemctl restart network
```

But when I run the above command, I receive this error:

> Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status network.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

When I run `systemctl status network.service`, I receive some errors:

> network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
>
> Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
>
> Unit network.service entered failed state.
>
> network.service failed.

#### Question

<s>I assume I need to install some package. What package is needed?</s> What's the error cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigating the `journalctl -xe` log helped me figure out the error cause.

The error was due to:

1. Wrong `DEVICE=eth0`

   - Resolved by renaming `DEVICE=eth0` to `DEVICE=enp9s0`
2. Existence of some copied files like `ifcfg-*` which I created for testing

   - Resolved by deleting them

Answer (score -1):

You can check whether the configuration file is wrong.

It worked for me when I changed `BOOTPROTO` to static.

Answer (score -2):

maybe your port 21 was in used, you can check like this:

> netstat -nalp | grep 21
>
> tcp6       0      0 :::21 :::* LISTEN      2028/proftpd

port 21 was used by another program, stop it and try restart:

> systemctl start vsftpd.service